# Git Master Branch - how do I undo chnages from a Deleted branch?

Tags: git

I was trying to get spork installed on my ROR application.  Using Git, I created a branch called spork and modified a few files.  After several hours trying to get spork to work, I am giving up on it and just want to back to how things were before.  I checked-out the master branch and then deleted the spork branch.

I know this is such a newb question but I can't find the answer.  What is the last step to get all the files changed back to how they were before on the master?

-TIA

Comment: Sorry, just needed to be desperate enough to look harder. git reset --hard HEAD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did the right thing by creating the branch for your experiment with spork integration; however, when you decided to give up on spork, your best bet would have been to either commit your changes in your spork branch, or discard your changes before checking the master branch back out and deleting the spork branch.

If you have unstaged changes in your working branch, and you checkout a different branch, the changes will actually show up in the other branch as well.  You can see this if you do a `git status` on your first branch, then checkout a different branch and do another `git status` - the unstaged changes are still there!  If you think about it, this makes sense - the unstaged changes are not being tracked by git, so it can't automatically "stash" them away when switching branches - it just leaves them where they are.  This is one of the slightly confusing/annoying behaviors that throw people (including me) off when starting with git.

To commit your changes, just do the normal `git add`, `git commit` flow.  To discard your working changes in a branch, you can do a `git checkout -- <files>`.  You can also do a `git reset --hard HEAD` to get rid of any changes you've made in a branch, and reset it to the latest commit.

Comment: Thank You for a more detailed explanation of what is happening in Git.  Its taking me longer to get a handle on git and rspec than I thought it would